# How to compare unique values of a series to the unique values in a column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df where a column contains state names. So `df.state.unique` gives me the unique values.

How can I compare it to a complete list/series of states `["State 1", "State 2"]`?
As a result, I would like to get a list all of states don't show up in `df.state` (by name, not True/False), such as "Alabama, Florida", for instance.

Comment: You might want to create a list with `.values.tolist()` and then compare each row with the operator `in` with the list of all states. The comparison can be done with `np.where` if you provide some sample data I can help you out and build a case example for you :)

Comment: Thanks, the other suggestion already worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, sets are the way to go. Let's say your complete list of states is called `states`:

```
 missing_states = set(states) - set(df.state.unique())
```

Comment: Thanks Juan, this worked perfectly well, so I found my four missing states.

Comment: I'm glad it did! Could you mark it as the accepted answer so it doesn't remain open? Thanks !

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see anything but the "flag" button before, as the check mark isn't to obvious for newbies. The official help page could really use a screenshot on this, too. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers